# Message-size error when trying to receive a small UDP packet

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, udp

When I call `Socket.ReceiveFrom` I get the following exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.

However, I have only sent a packet with 118 bytes.

The code is quite simple:

```
numBytesRead = udpSocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref _udpRemoteEndPoint);
```

Where data is allocated to 1200 bytes.

What am I doing wrong?

It's worth mentioning that I get this error only when running on **Windows** - the code works well on my Mac.

A few more details: I am writing in C# code in Unity (game engine).
I have one `TCP` socket and one `UDP` socket open on each machine. I am using a `Select` loop to handle both in the same thread, so I call `ReceiveFrom` only after I know that data is available. I'm using `TcpClient` and `UdpClient` to create the sockets.

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21876089/1731454) is different because I'm not sending big packets. I don't suppose my 118-byte payload should overflow any internal buffer.

Comment: Q: " I get this error only when running on Windows..."  A: that's because it's a limitation in the .Net System.Net.Sockets library, not "sockets" per se.,  RECOMMENDATIONS: declare a larger buffer, or find a different networking library besides System.Net.Sockets.  ALSO: consider using `ReceiveAsync` for partial reads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876089/

Comment: @paulsm4 The notion that System.Net.Sockets can't handle 118 byte packets is ridiculous. Please cite where you got that.

Comment: I never said it can't handle 118 byte packets.  Rather, I was trying to get the OP to focus on the .Net library - and how he was using it - rather than "Windows" or "sockets" in general.  My advice remains.

Comment: I have tried to enlarge the buffer and used ReceiveAsync - still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set enough space for the buffer:
byte[] data = new byte[1024];

Also the call is made this way:
udpSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref _udpRemoteEndPoint);
where ar is IAsyscResult type.

Comment: Thanks, the data was allocated indeed. I used ReceiveFrom, not EndReceiveFrom. No big difference.